# I can't run code when it have " in "s

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I can't run this process in C#;

```
var process3 = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c echo -ne "HTCU" | dd of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 seek=33796");
        process3.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\` to escape the quotes, like so:

```
\"
```

Your code line will look like this:

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c echo -ne \"HTCU\" | dd of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3 bs=1 seek=33796");
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm a beginner so can you write the full code for me?

Comment: Another option to escape the string is to prefix it with @"string to escape"